# Delete file in history by filter-branch but still can show

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

And:

I want to delete some garbarge large file from git repository, Then

### Long to short

Why file that deleted still show in `git rev-list --all --objects` and can be show `git show xxxxxx`

### Full version:

> Omit a really long time for research, Demo below is unrealistic, I use this demo to show how wrong it gose: Even delete everything except .gitignore.

**PS: I'm using linux and tmpfs for speedup**

First I use

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch *' HEAD
```

As it design, This only affect git but the file. So file still there by `ls` (for HEAD^)

Then, I tried

```bash
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf *' HEAD
```

Much slower, But all file is deleted. Except `.gitignore` . But repo size is not decrease.

Then, there are variation:

I use those command to delete all un-ref file.

```bash
git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Here is things go wrong. Size is not shrink. And `git rev-list --all --objects` and can still show file content with `git show xxxxxx`.

So file can be show mean the file is not deleted.

Question: What I missed? How to really delete a file from an repo? (Include all commit, all ref, all history, all content, just like never happen)

Comment: Use `filter-repo`. Note that you must delete the file from HEAD yourself (the instructions are clear).

Comment: `git filter-branch` does not remove objects. It creates new commits to replace the old history. So, the local repository size does not shrink. The number of the objects referenced by the rewritten refs gets smaller. After you push these refs to the remote repository, a new clone will download these rewritten refs with a smaller size of packed objects.

Comment: @ElpieKay I see, I thought gc will shrink pack size after filter-branch, So its only shrink size after I push to origin and someone else clone repo. Consider write an answer ? BTW: I tried BFG.jar and pack size do shrink on local, but non-vanila method is off topic.